# creating custom php error log file

Tags: php, apache, error-handling, logfile

Is there multiple error logs within a apache? meaning is there a php log, an apache log etc?
As through research I've seen error log paths extend into the document root with the file type of `file` or through many folder such as `/var/tmp/my-errors.log`

- What is the difference between these error logs?
- What does `var` and `tmp` mean? and was this created by the user or is it inside apache?
- Is a file with a file type of `file` unserviceable by apache? as my server creates a error log for php within my document root with the file type of `file`, is this a standard thing?

I want to create a error log file but how do I create one and where to I put it to make it unreadable, unserviceable to a user?

do I create it in document root with the file extension of `.log`, or outside the document root as everything there is in fact unserviceable by apache?

**I would like my log file to be within the document root, and to be unserviceable by apache, do I do this by creating a file with a file type of `file` and if so how do I do this?**

Comment: What is file type of file?

Comment: When you create a file within windows it displays a file type, it may be a "php file" or "file folder" or "file", I guess it means it has no file type

Comment: you definitely need to learn some filesystem basics, other than watching some Windows Explorer windows. Some key terms: path, filename, extension

Comment: extension! that's the word, I was just completely put of by the extension file so referred to it a different way and that caused me to refer to all the extensions that way, thanks anyway, cleared a few things up

Comment: but theres no need to mark the question down, I asked the question as I was unsure, because I got a few terms wrong in the questions just really requires answers or corrections; not a mark down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the difference between these error logs?

Apache generally only has an `access.log` storing information about which files have been requested and a generall `error.log` storing all (or most) errors that occurred during fullfilling any requests.

You can control whether the latter contains php errors or not via the php.ini directive `log_errors`.

> What does var and tmp mean? and was this created by the user or is it inside apache?

`/var` is the linux standard directory for shared user data.
`/var/tmp` is a non-standard directory, but the name `tmp` always hints disposable data.

> Is a file with a file type of file unserviceable by apache? as my server creates a error log for php within my document root with the file type of file, is this a standard thing?

Having the logs within the servable area is definitely not standard and even imposes a security threat. Logfiles should be kept outside of the web reachable area.

And if Apache couldnt serve files, what else would it serve?